# Find out what version of Boost was used to compile an executable/DLL

Tags: c++, boost

Is there any way to use "strings" or some otehr command to decide what version of Boost was used to compile a particular executable or .so? All I have is the executable/.so itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost is mostly a header-only library, with extensive use of templates (which all compiles down to probably some optimized binary). Given only the executable binary, you're most likely not be able to deduce the Boost version used.

Probably the only way you'll know what Boost version is used by looking at the executable's version number (if it has one) then look it up in the source control repository it came from (if you have access to it).

Comment: There is http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/version.hpp, but the version is #define-d, so no I don't think you'll find a Boost version string in the binary unless the programmer explicitly put it there.